# PowerShell URL redirect from root to subdirectory

Tags: powershell, iis, http-redirect

I'm trying to build a deployment script in PowerShell to replace the manual work of using the IIS user interface (this is for a Docker container).  The one step I cannot find is how to navigate users from the root url to the app folder.   So if users navigate to [www.site.com](http://www.site.com), they go to www.site.com\WebSampleTest.

This is what I have so far:

```
Set-WebConfiguration system.webServer/httpRedirect "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -Value @{enabled="true";destination="WebSampleTest";exactDestination="true";httpResponseStatus="Permanent"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpRedirect" -name "enabled" -value "True"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpRedirect" -name "destination" -value "websampletest"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpRedirect" -name "httpResponseStatus" -value "Permanent"
```

Comment: Bruce Zhang, any chance this won't work on localhost:port?  I'm running the Set-WebConfigurationProperty lines after I run the New-WebApplication command. Still no luck.

Comment: When you run the set-webconfigurationProperty, is there any error information? What new-webApplication command did you run?

Comment: It looks like I was missing the following in my PowerShell script:
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Redirect

(see my post below)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the add the WindowsFeature below:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Redirect
```

And then added the following code for the actual redirect:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpRedirect" -name "enabled" -value "True"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpRedirect" -name "destination" -value "WebSampleTest"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpRedirect" -name "childOnly" -value "true"
```